# getting data from php variable

Tags: php, variables, foreach

$content = file_get_contents('file.php');

echo $content;

nothing displays, expect when displaying the page sourcecode in browser the display is this

```
<? foreach(glob("folder/*.php") as $class_filename) { require_once($class_filename); } ?>
```

so it wont execute the script when getting the content..

file.php contains this code
`<? foreach(glob("folder/*.php") as $class_filename) {
require_once($class_filename);
}
?>`

and if I do next

```
$content = foreach(glob("folder/*.php") as $class_filename) { require_once($class_filename); } ?>
```

it complains about unexpected foreach...

is there a way to read the folder/*.php files content to single $variable and then echo/print all folder/*.php files to page where it should be?

thanks for help already.

Comment: Could you print the error messages you're getting exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want to do ?

```
$content = '';
foreach (glob('folder/*.php') as $class){$content .= file_get_contents($class);}
echo $content;
```

Comment: actually yes.. 
but both answers are good and I can use them. :)
thanks

Comment: No, DaveyBoy code is better if you want to **execute** the php code. Mine will not execute the code in the file, it will just read the file content. So if you need to execute your files, use DaveyBoy code, if you don't need it mine is better (because you don't eval files). This is two different usage.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying won't execute the contents of the "file.php", jsut display the contents of them on screen.

If you want to execute file.php, use `eval ($content)`

To capture the output, use something like:

```
ob_start();              // Don't echo anything but buffer it up

$codeToRun=file_get_contents('file.php'); // Get the contents of file.php
eval ($codeToRun);       // Run the contents of file.php
$content=ob_get_flush(); // Dump anything that should have been echoed to a variable and stop buffering

echo $content;           //echo the stuff that should have been echoed above
```